# SED/AWK how to replace a value if a parent key matches in json file

Tags: json, linux, awk, sed, jq

I'm trying to replace the default value if the parent is refreshinterval.I have tried using jq and sed but unable to get my expected output. Can someone help to get the expected answer.

```
{ "doubleClickDiff": {
        "type": "boolean",
        "title": "Show diff on double click",
        "description": "If true, doubling clicking a file in the list of changed files will open a diff.",
        "default": false
      },
      "historyCount": {
        "type": "integer",
        "title": "History count",
        "description": "Number of (most recent) commits shown in the history log",
        "default": 25
      },
      "refreshInterval": {
        "type": "integer",
        "title": "Refresh interval",
        "description": "Number of milliseconds between polling the file system for changes.",
        "default": 10000
      },
      "simpleStaging": {
        "type": "boolean",
        "title": "Simple staging flag",
        "description": "If true, use a simplified concept of staging. Only files with changes are shown (instead of showing staged/changed/untracked), and all files with changes will be automatically staged",
        "default": false
      }}
```

my output should replace default value only if key is refreshInterval

```
"refreshInterval": {
        "type": "integer",
        "title": "Refresh interval",
        "description": "Number of milliseconds between polling the file system for changes.",
        "default": 40000
      },



jq '."refreshInterval"."default"=40000' plugin.json

sed -i 's/\"default\":.*/\"default\": '40000'/g' "demo.json"
```

Comment: `jq` is definitely the way to go. `jq '.refreshInterval.default = 40000' plugin.json` should [work just fine](https://jqplay.org/s/TJpYM4bu41) but you need to write the output back into your file. For instance `jq '...' > jq_output; mv jq_output plugin.json` (don't do `jq '...' file > file`, the redirection will erase the content of `file` before it is read by `jq`)

Comment: @Aaron, that should be an answer

Comment: i have the same answer but it is updating actual answer like this "refreshInterval": {
    "default": 30000
  }

Answer (score 2):

The `jq` command you've posted [should work just fine](https://jqplay.org/s/TJpYM4bu41), but it doesn't update the file, it just outputs the updated result. You can store that output and overwrite the original file with it as follows :

```
jq '.refreshInterval.default = 40000' plugin.json > jq_output
mv jq_output plugin.json
```

Careful not to try to simplify it into `jq '.refreshInterval.default = 40000' plugin.json > plugin.json` as the redirection will be processed first and erase the content of the file before `jq` can read it. If you want to avoid the use of a temporary file you could use an utility such as `sponge` from the `moreutils` package which allows in-place edition.

Comment: it is giving another entry instead of updating the result. can you help w.r.t this `"refreshInterval": {
      "type": "integer",
      "title": "Refresh interval",
      "description": "Number of milliseconds between polling the file system for changes.",
      "default": 10000
    },
  },
  "refreshInterval": {
    "default": 30000`

Comment: @Auto-learner it seems that the path to the value you wish to edit should be `.something.refreshInterval.default`, I assume the JSON you've posted was just an extract?

Comment: @Auto-learner here's a jqplay that reproduces your problem : https://jqplay.org/s/hKSWD5NbuI. The path to `default` should be `.outerField.refreshInterval.default` but since we missed the `.outerField` we create a new object rather than update the target `refreshInterval` object